# Laravel create, undefined indexes

Tags: php, laravel, forms, edit

I'm trying to edit users, but "undefined index"is returning. i'm using this current script to edit and associate ADDRESS information with users.

```
 public function getIndexEditClient(Request $request, $id) {
    $regions = DB::table("regions")->pluck("name","id");
    $address = Address::where('id', $request->address_id)->with('region')->first();
    $clients = $this->data->getEditClient($id);

    //als gebruiker geen address heeft, creeer deze en koppel hem aan user
    if (!isset($address)){
        $data = $request->input();

        $address = Address::create([
            'region'        => $data['region'],
            'country'       => $data['country'],
            'city'          => $data['city'],
            'street_name'   => $data['street_name'],
            'house_number'  => $data['house_number'],
            'postcode'      => $data['postcode']
        ]);

         //create associate user with address
        $clients->address()->associate($address);
        $address = new Address;
        $address->this->save();
```

Else is working fine.

This is my edit form:

```
** <h3>Address information</h3>                     
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Region</label>
                        <select id="region" name="region" class="form-control">
                        <option value="{{$address['region => id']}}" selected>{{$address['region => name']}}</option>
                            @foreach($regions as $key => $region)
                            <option value="{{$key}}"> {{$region}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Country</label>
                                <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control">
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

etc etc

**
Is my way of adding a address wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You want to save an array,meanwhile you are saving an object,it will be better to use this format instead. SO change the way you want to save the Address

```
$data = new Address();            
$data->region=$request->region;
$data->country=$request->country;
$data->city=$request->city;
  ...
 $data->save();

$address = Address::create([
'region'        => $data['region'],
'country'       => $data['country'],
 'city'          => $data['city'],
'street_name'   => $data['street_name'],
'house_number'  => $data['house_number'],
'postcode'      => $data['postcode']
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel automatically removes empty values from the request, so if one of the fields has been left empty it will not be in the `$data` array.

You should either add validation to your post back or check for each value if the key exists on the `$data` array.

Answer (score 0):

Try dumping the request

```
dd($request->all());
```

If all the values are coming you can use

```
$address = Address::create($request->all());
```

Comment: $data = $request->input(); he's saying the inputs are the data as you can see

Comment: $address = Address::create([
            'region'        => $data['region'],
            'country'       => $data['country'],
            'city'          => $data['city'],
            'street_name'   => $data['street_name'],
            'house_number'  => $data['house_number'],
            'postcode'      => $data['postcode']
        ]);